# Can we create Push topics on external objects?

Tags: lightning-connect, streaming-api, pushtopic

I have set up a Push Topic on an external object to look for the 'Create' Activity. However, when I create an External object record, the Workbench Push Topic Window doesn't receive a Message. Is there some limitation with using Push topics with External objects?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe External Objects are supported at all, only the following Objects:

> Supported Objects in PushTopic Queries:
>
> 1. PushTopic queries support all custom objects. PushTopic queries
>      support the following standard objects.
> 2. Account
> 3. Campaign
> 4. Case
> 5. Contact
> 6. Lead
> 7. Opportunity
> 8. Task
>
> The following standard objects are supported in PushTopic queries
>   through a pilot program.
>
> 1. ContractLineItem
> 2. Entitlement
> 3. LiveChatTranscript
> 4. Quote
> 5. QuoteLineItem
> 6. ServiceContract

It is also important to take into consideration that not all SOQL queries are supported.

[Suported PushTopic Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/supported_soql.htm) (Supported Objects are listed here)

[Unsuported PushTopic Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/unsupported_soql_statements.htm)

[Compound Fields in PushTopic Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/pushtopic_queries_compound_fields.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm checking up with Salesforce support for the same. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @Kanav Khurana, i'm pretty sure SF support will reply with the above. However a definite answer from them to confirm this would definitely be helpful. additionally, I believe they would have mentioned External objects in the documentation if they were supported, not sure they would write a list of all unsupported objects if most of them aren't.